# How to remove : from string and get other elements?

Tags: c++, string

So, I have to make the following program:

I input two "clocks", in format HH:MM, and I have to check the difference between them in minutes and output it. Then I have to check which time has bigger size, in minutes, and output which time is bigger or if they are equal.

So, I've done this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a, b, c, d;
    int a_min, b_min;

    getline(cin, a, ':');
    cin >> b;

    getline(cin, c, ':');
    cin >> d;

    a_min = atoi(a.c_str()) * 60 + atoi(b.c_str());

    b_min = atoi(c.c_str()) * 60 + atoi(d.c_str());

    if (a_min > b_min){
        cout << "Razlikata iznesuva " << a_min - b_min << " minuti" << endl;
        cout << "Pogolemo e prvoto vreme" << endl;
    }
    else if (b_min > a_min){
        cout << "Razlikata iznesuva " << b_min - a_min << " minuti" << endl;
        cout << "Pogolemo e vtoroto vreme" << endl;
    }
    else if (a_min == b_min){
        cout << "Vreminjata se isti" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But when you input HH:MM, I have a ":" between the HH and MM, therefore I can't get the numbers simply, so I need help how to get hours and minutes and convert them (conversion should be easy I guess) or if there's alternative and better method for this?

Comment: Hm, this is much easier with standard C library (scanf) than the C++ one.

Comment: Well, I have to do this in C++ unfortunately...

Comment: Take a look at the answers to [How to split a string in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c/236803#236803)

Comment: @user2699298, there is nothing (aside from ill judgement) which prevents you from using C library functions in C++ programs. Like Jan Hudec says, it's *easier* with `fscanf`, use it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should be reading NUMBERS, not strings. Numbers are read until non-digit, so will stop at `:`:

   ```
   char dummy;
   int hour, minute;
   cin >> hour >> dummy >> minute;
   // check dummy == ':'
   ```
2. Strings are read until whitespace. And the whitespace is not skipped unless you've set [skipws](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/skipws/). However there is a function that allows reading string until specific separator:

   ```
   string hour, minute;
   getline(cin, hour, ':'); // this will eat the `:`
   cin >> minute; // assuming whitespace or eof after this
   // check the values, that you didn't cross eof and such.
   ```

Comment: ok, so here's what I tried: `string a, b, a_min, b_min;
    char c;
    getline(cin, a, ':');
    cin >> c >> b;
    cout << a << " " << b;`
And for input 12:33, I get only a=12, b=3, one number in b is skipped for some reason.

Comment: @user2699298: ... of course; sorry, getline will eat the `:`.

Comment: @user: Get rid of `dummy`, the `getline` specification says "the delimiter character is extracted from input, but is not appended to str"

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, I noticed.

Comment: I managed to get it working now, I'll try to finish the program with this for now. Let's see how it goes! :)

Comment: It's not enough to check only `dummy`. You also have to check that `hour` is in interval [0, 24) and `minute` is in interval [0, 60).

Answer (score 1):

Use a `std::istringstream` to do the parsing for you; this expects time stamps in 24-hours format:

```
static unsigned int minutesSinceMidnight( const std::string &timeStamp )
{
    unsigned int hours, minutes;
    char colon;
    std::istringstream( timeStamp ) >> hours >> colon >> minutes;
    return hours * 60 + minutes;
}
```

You can then compare two time stamps easily and also tell how many minutes they are apart.

Comment: Why don't you do the parsing on `cin` directly? All streams have the same capabilities!

Comment: @JanHudec: Not using `std::cin` greatly simplifies testing the code (if I wanted to support *all* kinds of streams, I'd probably have used `std::istream` directly). Maybe this is just the Haskell mindset in me, but I try to separate the code doing IO from the code which purely transforms arguments into a return value.

Comment: Yes, getting an istream as argument would be the most sensible way. Easy to test and easy to apply directly to input. But this is just unnecessarily longer.

Comment: So, I want to implement this code without usage of functions and here is my code and I get an error. `string a, b, a_min, b_min;
    cin >> a >> b;
    unsigned int casovi, minuti;
    char c;
    istringstream ( a ) >> casovi >> c >> minuti;
    a_min = casovi * 60 + minuti;
    cout << a_min;` and the error I get is: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct std::istringstream for istringstream function.

Comment: @user2699298: Make sure to `#include <sstream>`

Comment: I did it, and here's the code: `string a, a_min; cin >> a; unsigned int hours, minutes; char c; istringstream ( a ) >> hours >> minutes; a_min = hours * 60 + minutes; cout << a_min; return 0;` but I get some weird characters as results.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
int h,m;
char separator;
cin >> h >> separator >> m;
if(separator == ':' && h>=0 && h < 24 && m >=0 && m < 60)
{
  // you have a correct hour
}
```

Comment: Well, I guess there has to be space in this case? And is it possible to use operator >, < etc with string?

Comment: You're right, regex does the job here, but unfortunately I haven't learned it yet, so I need alternative option like strings / chars if possible.

Comment: This won't fly. If you read the hours and minutes directly as numbers, they'd stop on any character. But strings won't. The first string will eat it all, IIRC the separator will get the newline and the last string will get nothing.

Comment: that was just a slip from copying from the original post. things like `h>=0 && h < 24` would not work if h was a `string`